# Why is my video code not working in Internet Explorer and Safari?

Tags: html, video

Why isn't this working in Internet Explorer and Safari?

```
<video loop autoplay controls muted="" width="100%" height="auto">
    <source src="http://modified-template3.medien-host4.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/template.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="http://modified-template3.medien-host4.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/template.webm"  type="video/webm" />
</video>
```

Comment: Probably a version problem, all browsers tends to share more and more functionnality, but there is a reason why developpers avoids explorer and safari like the plague : they do not. It's more likely that you'll need to implement another way to do this using features provided by internet explorer and safari.

Comment: Your video is not playing or its about the attribute.

Comment: Works for me in IE 11.309.16299.0 Windows 10 Client